# UIImageView with partial transparent doesn't work

Tags: ios, background, uiimageview, png, transparent

I have a png file with partial transparent and I want to set it as background of my UIImageView.
I have actually this code :

```
        generalFond = [[UIImageViewTouchable alloc] initWithFrame:ScrollViewGeneral.frame];
        [generalFond.layer setOpaque:YES];
        generalFond.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[imageCacheManager getUIImage:carte.carte_template.fondUrl]];
        [generalFond.layer setOpaque:NO];
        generalFond.opaque = NO;
        generalFond.delegate = self;
        [ScrollViewGeneral addSubview:generalFond];
```

I don't understand what's the problem...
My UiImageView have a white background where png file is transparent

Thanks

Robin

Comment: From a quick Google search, colorWithPatternImage seems to be buggy with transparent images. Since you are using a UIImageView, is there any reason you can't just set the image property of it, instead of the background color?

Comment: There are no reason it's just doesn't work

Comment: Thanks Geon
I have found my problem.
In my ImageCacheManager, i use a UIImageJPEGRepresentation instead of UIImagePNGRepresentation

With UIImagePNGRepresentation it's ok

Comment: If you are not going to use the view as an UIImageView, use a plain UIView instead. Otherwise, it's very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do the following

```
   generalFond = [[UIImageViewTouchable alloc] initWithFrame:ScrollViewGeneral.frame];
   [generalFond.layer setOpaque:YES];
   generalFond.image = [imageCacheManager getUIImage:carte.carte_template.fondUrl];
   generalFond.backGroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   [generalFond.layer setOpaque:NO];
   generalFond.opaque = NO;
   generalFond.delegate = self;
   [ScrollViewGeneral addSubview:generalFond];
```

Comment: Thanks Omar Abdelhafith
I have found my problem.
In my ImageCacheManager, i use a UIImageJPEGRepresentation instead of UIImagePNGRepresentation

With UIImagePNGRepresentation it's ok

Comment: as this is not the answer you are looking for why you accept it instead of just put your answer and accept it as other user will follow the above answer because you accept it will lead them to wrong direction i think so